# How to do code completion of annotation fields in Intellij?

Tags: annotations, intellij-idea

Imagine the following code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cas)
```

How can I invoke code completion of the 'cas' to use 'cascade' option of the @nnotation?

Comment: Which version of IDEA and OS are you using? After typying `cas` IntelliJ displays *cascade* pop-up automatically and I can show it on demand using Ctrl + space at any time.

Comment: I'm using version 12 and osx. Ctrl + space is now working for me as well, but it wasn't earlier (don't know the reason).

Comment: So probably this question should be closed.